# How do I properly expose my public signing key for CAS generated JWT tickets

Tags: jwt, rsa, cas

## UPDATE:

After further testing it seems as though the RSA setup I thought was working, actually isn't. Until CAS can support asymmetric keys for JWT tickets, this question is rendered irrelevant.

### My use case:

**CAS VERSION: 6.2.0-RC2**

Using CAS for single sign on for a number of applications. The backend identity provider is LDAP. The client of interest is an SPA that redirects to CAS for login. Upon successful login to CAS, a JWT is issued via a configured service provider. I have setup the service provider to sign the JWT using asymmetric keys via RSA. This is all working. What I can't get to work is the "jwtTicketSigningPublicKey" actuator endpoint.

I want to be able to publish the public key so that my SPA is able to dynamically grab the public key for signage validation so that I can rotate the RSA keys if necessary without having to change anything on the SPA side. I assumed this was the purpose for this feature, but when I hit the endpoint after exposing it as directed [here](https://apereo.github.io/2018/11/06/cas6-admin-endpoints-security/), I get a 404.

### My config:

Here is what my cas.config file looks like as it relates to this endpoint:

```
# Expose it
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=jwtTicketSigningPublicKey
# Enable it
management.endpoint.jwtTicketSigningPublicKey.enabled=true
# Allow access to it
cas.monitor.endpoints.endpoint.jwtTicketSigningPublicKey.access=ANONYMOUS
```

I then bounce the CAS server and I can see the endpoint in the actuator links at http://mycas.com/cas/actuator like so:

```
"jwtTicketSigningPublicKey":{"href":"http://mycas.com/cas/actuator/jwtTicketSigningPublicKey","templated":false}
```

As the document refers to, I can pass an optional service parameter like so to get the public key associated to a "per-service" implementation, which is what I have. I hit the endpoint like so:

```
http://mycas.com/cas/actuator/jwtTicketSigningPublicKey?service=http://example.org
```

At which point I receive a 404. I also get a 404 if I hit the endpoint without the service parameter. But I would expect that since I don't actually have a globally defined RSA pair.

### My attempt at a solution:

The most logical place I can imagine this public key should be provided is in the service configuration along with where I am providing the private key. However I can find no documented parameter by which to define the public key. This is what I have tried to no avail.

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId" : "^http://.*",
  "name" : "Sample",
  "id" : 10,
  "properties" : {
    "@class" : "java.util.HashMap",
    "jwtAsServiceTicket" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "true" ] ]
    },
    "jwtSigningSecretAlg" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "RS256" ] ]
    },
    "jwtAsServiceTicketSigningKey" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "MyPrivateKeyGoesHere" ] ]
    },
    "jwtAsServiceTicketSigningPublicKey" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "MyPublicKeyGoesHere" ] ]
    }
  }
}
```

The signing key works and is a [documented parameter](https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html#configure-keys-per-service). Also, the signing secret algorithm is documented [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/JWT-Authentication.html#configuration). But the last "...SigningPublicKey" parameter was a complete shot in the dark because I have not found any docs on the matter other than what is defined [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html#administrative-endpoints).

### Summary:

So what I am hoping to find by this question, is someone that is familiar with this endpoint and how to configure it properly in order to make the signing public key available to my SPA.